# Split data frame column into multiple column

Tags: r

Working in R.
I have a data set see below. I want to have two different columns for "No. of Export partners" and "No. Of Import partners" instead of them being combined under "indicator". What should i do? Have tried the pivot commands but could not figure out how to make it work.

```
# A tibble: 747 x 4 
reporter indicator              year      value
<chr>    <chr>                  <chr>     <dbl>
1 Aruba    No. Of Export partners year_2018     6
2 Aruba    No. Of Export partners year_2016    15
3 Aruba    No. Of Export partners year_2014    21
4 Aruba    No. Of Import partners year_2018    20
5 Aruba    No. Of Import partners year_2016    23
6 Aruba    No. Of Import partners year_2014    22
7 Angola   No. Of Export partners year_2018   138
8 Angola   No. Of Export partners year_2016   135
9 Angola   No. Of Export partners year_2014    38
10 Angola   No. Of Import partners year_2018   183
# … with 737 more rows
```

Comment: Instead of posting your data like you have done, could you use `dput()` and paste in the output? That will allow us to more easily copy the data into R. Here are some other tips on making a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes thank you. First time posting - tried to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Should be easier to see now.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please edit your post to include your data.  The following code will generate a code snippet with 10 random records that you can paste into your original post: dput(dplyr::sample_n(YourDatasetsNameGoesHere, 10)). To use my code, you may need to install dplyr with: install.packages("dplyr")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `tidyverse` packages, specifically `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `stringr`.

```
library(tidyverse)
your_data %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = indicator,   # This does what you want
              values_from = value) %>%  
  mutate(year = as.numeric(str_sub(year, 6)))  # converts your year column into numeric
```